# How to keep previous screen state when switch between drawer item

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When i switch between screens, the previous state of the screen will be lost and the screen will be re render as a new component. How i keep the state of screen? I want to keep things as text field value, scroll list offset..

Please guide, thanks

Comment: `previous state of the screen will be lost`. This isn't true. All screens state will remain same unless popped of the stack. Which navigation library are you using? Need some code to understand better. Look into Redux or Mobx for state management.

Comment: I using react-navigation for react-native app. I have two screens A and B, use DrawerNavigator as main navigator, when i change some state (eg input some text to a field) then press B item and then press A item but all new state of A be lost. I dont want use redux to keep state, i think has a way to keep it. The A component should not re mount, it should re open again with previous state.